# Convert async code to promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I use the following code and I need to convert it to promise and at the end return object which contain the file configuration,
how should I do that ?

```
 var Promise = require('bluebird'),
      glob = promisifyAll(require("glob")),
      fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require("fs"));

module.exports = {
    parse: function (configErr) {
    glob("folder/*.json", function (err, files) {
      if (err) {
        return configErr(new Error("Error to read json files: " + err));
      }
      files.forEach(function (file) {
        fs.readFileAsync(file, 'utf8', function (err, data) { // Read each file
          if (err) {
            return configErr(new Error("Error to read config" + err));
          }
          return JSON.parse(data);
        });
      })
    })
```

**UPDATE** -in the code I want to get json files from specific folder in my node project and parse the json content to object

Comment: You should explain what you are actually trying to do as well.

Comment: how about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521117/converting-async-code-to-q-promise-code-in-nodejs

Comment: @thefourtheye- I'll update my question ASAP with the data you ask

Comment: @thefourtheye -Done !

Comment: @shopiaT After parsing you are ignoring it.

Comment: @thefourtheye - this is all the code for this module parse json file to object

Comment: @thefourtheye - see my updated post

Comment: Why convert it to promises? Most asyncness is used by the module itself. `configErr` seems to be the only external callback, pretty easy.

Comment: Look at the Promisification section of bluebird - https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisification

Comment: "*at the end return object which contain the file configuration*" -  that won't work, as you're loading the files asynchronously. The best bet is to return a promise for the configuration.

Comment: @Bergi - Can you please show as answer how to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Promisified functions return promises, you should use those instead of passing callbacks into the invocation. Btw, your `forEach` loop does not work asynchronously, you should use a [dedicated promise function](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) for that.

```
 var Promise = require('bluebird'),
     globAsync = Promise.promisify(require("glob")),
     fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require("fs"));

module.exports.parse = function() {
    return globAsync("folder/*.json").catch(function(err) {
        throw new Error("Error to read json files: " + err);
    }).map(function(file) {
        return fs.readFileAsync(file, 'utf8').then(JSON.parse, function(err) {
            throw new Error("Error to read config ("+file+")" + err);
        });
    });
};
```

Then you can import this promise, and catch errors or use the array of parsed config objects by attaching callbacks to it via `.then`.

```
var config = require('config');
config.parse().then(function(cfg) { … }, function onConfigErr(err) { … })
```

Comment: Thanks I try it and I got error undefined is not a function in the .catch(function(err) { ,any idea?

Comment: @shopiaT: Please log the result of the `globAsync` call to see what it is. [Promisification](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html) should work fine on `glob`.

Comment: How should I log it ?

Comment: But how I got error when I run it ,Do you want me to change the code?

Comment: Yes, please use standard debugging techniques. If you don't want to point a debugger at node, edit the code and insert `console.log` statements where appropriate.

Comment: I think I know what is the problem, assume that I want to call to this functionality parse(as my question post): function () { .... how should I call it ? can you please update the answer with it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84936/discussion-between-shopia-t-and-bergi).

Comment: I've removed the `parse` method from the module as it looked quite unnecessary. The files start to load when the module is loaded, and the results are exported as a promise. You can use that like `require('config').then(function(cfg) { … }, function(err) { … })`